# How to cast a java Object to an arbitrary other type

Tags: java, object, casting

We're trying to set up a secure IPC channel between an app and a service.  To that end, we're providing an `encrypt()` and a `decrypt()` function that are used on both ends of the communication channel.  The `encrypt()` function takes an arbitrary Java object, uses `json-io` to convert it to an array of bytes which is encrypted and converted to a `String` through base 64 encoding.  The `decrypt()` function is supposed to do the opposite - take the b64 `String`, convert it to bytes which are decrypted, then run back through `json-io` to restore the original object.

This probably works as expected, except that the `decrypt()` function returns an `Object`, since we don't know what type of object was passed into the `encrypt()` function.  Our expectation was that we'd be able to just cast the resulting `Object` to the correct type and return it to the client code.  However, the program fails with a

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to ...` error.

Is there a way to fix this in Java?  All of the reading I've found seems to indicate not, but I don't know if that's simply because I don't know the right question to ask or if Java just won't do it.  (Both my collaborator and I are from C++ backgrounds where this sort of thing is trivial.)

One possible solutions I thought of is having a different return type for the `decrypt()` function which ***can*** be cast to an arbitrary type, but I'd be surprised if there was such a beast.

Another idea is implementing a separate `decrypt()` function for each type of returned object, but that seems like a messy approach, and one that would become increasingly unwieldly as more types are added.

Is there a different question I should be asking?

Comment: Say I give you this JSON `{"random":"value"}`, what are you going to deserialize it to? How do you choose? What if multiple types fit that JSON object tree? There's nothing magic about serialization/deserialization.

Comment: Your plan should work as you expect. Something else is wrong in one of the translation layers. It looks to me like type information is being lost; java.lang.Object is the base class of all base classes in Java and so very few objects are actually of type Object (usually just those used as synchronization locks and so forth).

Comment: If you store in that JSON what class you are serializing {"class":"com.foo.Bar"} then you could use that to do deserialization.

Comment: For example, when the client calls the `scListCertificates()` interface function, the server returns a `ListCertificatesOutputClass` object as expected by the client, so the client would cast the `Object` to a `ListCertificatesOutputClass`:  In each case, the casting is being done to a known type, which is different for each function interface call, but known at coding time.

Comment: @FilipBulovic: json-io already does that, and automates the deserialization, so something else is wrong.

Comment: Yes, @FredKoschara, that's allowed in Java (as you thought it would be). So you just need to debug, something else is wrong, not your basic idea. :) Basically in Java everything is like a C++ dynamic_cast, which will work the way you expect.

Comment: I don't know anything really about json-io, but I can tell you that a Java reflection-based framework (Java reflection = C++ RTTI) will need the classes being serialized to be present on both ends of the connection. Is that true in your application?

Comment: @DavidP.Caldwell and @FilipBulovic - This is why I said it "probably works as expected" - the problem is that the `decrypt()` function, being generic, only returns an `Object` not the specific type of object that was returned.  _Within_ the `decrypt()` function, I believe the object type is correct, it's just how to get it across `decrypt()`'s return call that I'm having a problem with.

Comment: The direct answer to your question is yes, you can use [`Class.cast(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29). But it can still `throw ClassCastException`, so I'm not sure what you are really trying to do.

Comment: @FredKoschara Well, if you need to know how to do a cast, it's (MyType)decrypt(myBytes) to cast the return value to MyType. But declaring the return type as Object is not your problem; no type information is actually lost and you should be able to cast it to the type you want after receiving it. And your ClassCastException indicates that it's not actually a MyType that is being returned.

Comment: @DavidP.Caldwell - a reflection-based framework - that sounds like what I need to look into - there's nothing like that being used.

Comment: Sorry, I mean json-io is a reflection-based framework, which it is (it retains type information and uses reflection to serialize and deserialize). But to deserialize a type it will need the Java class being deserialized to be present on the receiving end of the connection.

Comment: `ListCertificatesOutputClass out = (ListCertificatesOutputClass) dhdx.decryptObject(retData);` throws a `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to com.apperian.vpntestfixture.MainActivity$ListCertificatesOutputClass' error with `
    private class ListCertificatesOutputClass extends Object
    {
    }
' as the target class.  Is this possibly because `ListCertificatesOutputClass` is a private class within the application?

Comment: You cannot change the class of a Java object.  If the exception is reporting it as class `java.lang.Object` that means it is an object of that class, and it can never be cast to any other class (since Object is the base class of all other classes).  The only thing you can use cast for is converting between classes in the inheritance chain of the object.

Comment: @DavidP.Caldwell - yes the classes are declared and the same on both ends of the connection - or at least that's the design.

Comment: (I suspect that your `decrypt` function is seriously mucked up, possibly due to your incorrect assumptions.)

Comment: @HotLicks - we're not trying to **change** the class of the object, we're just trying to get an arbitrary object across the return of the `decrypt()` function which doesn't care what type of object it's returning.

Comment: You **are** trying to change the class of the object.  The exception reports the class of the object is `Class`, and that class cannot be cast to any other class.  If you want a different class then your decrypt function must create and return a different class.  (It can always return it as a value typed `Class`, to be up-cast by the caller, but the actual class of the object must be observed.)

Comment: Yeah, it's the "private" part that is the problem, I suspect.

Comment: Oops!!  I meant that the exception reports the class of the object to be **Object**.  If it's an Object it can't be cast to any other type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast a thing that is *declared* as an Object to any Class or Interface that it actually is, for instance

```
Object o = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString();
// o is declared as an object but is really a String

// this is fine
String s1 = (String) o;
// this is also fine because String implements CharSequence
CharSequence cs = (CharSequence) o;
```

Likewise, a method may be declared to return *Object* while it is returning some specific subclass(es) of Object, then the return can be cast to the specific thing being returned.

However, if a thing is built ***as*** an Object it can't be cast to anything; it may be *an Object that resembles a String*, but it is not an object of class String.

```
public Object getThing(final Object arg) {
    return new Object() {
        private String str = arg.toString();
        public String getStr() {
            return this.str;
        }
    };
}
```

The thing being returned here **is** an Object (is-a) though it's been extended with bits that can't be accessed (except through reflection) because they aren't part of java.lang.Object's contract.

One approach around this kind of thing is Java Generics. If you have `public Object decrypt(...)` you may be able to create `public T decrypt(...)` — but then you have to actually build objects of class or interface `T`, and generics is entirely another subject, too large to go into here.

So, it depends on what is *actually* being built and returned by your `decryptObject(...)` method for how you can go about casting the returned object.
To do a static cast as `(SomeClass) o` you have to already know what the thing is.

Comment: Aha! - it **is** related to my test fixture where the `ListCertificatesOutputClass` declaration is private within the test fixture.  This answer, along with comments @DavidP.Caldwell left on my original posting, have pointed me in the direction I need to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this answer to close the loop with my findings.

It turns out the problem was not that the `decrypt()` function was returning an `Object` that couldn't be cast to the correct type:  The real problem was the test code feeding a plain `Object` into the `encrypt()` function - and *that* `Object` is the one that could not be cast to a `ListCertificatesOutputClass`.  Once I set up an external definition of `ListCertificatesOutputClass` that could be used on both ends of the wire and passed that into `encrypt()`, casting the output of `decrypt()` worked as expected.